# Does `jar` have a flag to set the default class for the .jar file to be created?

Tags: java, class, jar, default

Or do we still need to write a `MANIFEST.mf` file manually for this?

Comment: Did you look at the [JAR tool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke the `jar` command with the `-e` Parameter. You do not have to manually add a manifest then. From `jar -help`

> ```
> -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
>     bundled into an executable jar file
> ```

An example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

> jar cfe Main.jar foo.Main foo/Main.class

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file specifies the starting class to call in the Main-Class: line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to write a `MANIFEST.mf` always, java machine run the `main class` in the `MANIFEST.mf` if don't have the `main class`, the .jar file do nothing

use NetBeans or Eclipse make automatically the `MANIFEST.mf` with `main class`